# Issues saving NSDictionary instances in NSArrays

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to copy the iOS Safari bookmark system. I have individual bookmarks working and folders in the main set working. I need help making it so I can have unlimited folders in other folders. Basically, my code right now can only save into 1 folder, so Main Folder → Folder 1 → Folder 2, but can't go past that. I have to quit the app after making folder 1 to save anything in it. Xcode gives me this error:

```
WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate: <NSInternalInconsistencyException> -[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

This is what a folder dictionary looks like:

```
NSDictionary *NewFolderDict = @{
    @"Title" : NewFolderTitle,
    @"isFolder" : @YES ,
    @"Bookmarks" : @[],
    @"UUID" : [self uuidString]
};
```

`Title` is the entry's name, `isFolder` is whether or not the entry is a folder, bookmarks is an array of bookmarks or more folders.

The whole main `NSArray` is in `NSUserDefaults`.

This is how I'm saving the folders now. This code is called when the user presses the done button on the keyboard in the view controller:

```
-(void)addDictionary:(NSDictionary *)FolderDictionary toFolder:(NSMutableDictionary*)toFolder {

    NSMutableArray *bookmarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"bookmarks"]];
    for (int i=0; i<[bookmarks count]; i++) {

        NSMutableDictionary *Bookmark = (NSMutableDictionary *)[bookmarks objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([[Bookmark objectForKey:@"isFolder"] boolValue] == YES) {

            if ([[Bookmark objectForKey:@"UUID"] isEqualToString:[toFolder objectForKey:@"UUID"]]) {
                NSLog(@"MATCH");
                NSMutableArray *test = (NSMutableArray *)[Bookmark objectForKey:@"Bookmarks"];
                [test addObject:FolderDictionary];

            }

        }

    }
    NSLog(@"%@",bookmarks);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"bookmarks"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [bookmarks release];

}
```

This just checks if it's a folder, and if it's the right folder to be adding to.  How can I make it work 100% of the time, and save it, and make it so it doesn't have a limit of how many folders it can go down, so like 10 folder stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that when fetching the data from the user defaults, they are immutable - i.e. they are instances of `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, and not `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableDictionary`. You might want to clone the the objects of interest, i.e. call `mutableCopy` on them and replace them in your data structure.